# Apache Ignite: What causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in StripedCompositeReadWriteLock?

Tags: ignite

We have services written in Kotlin, which are behaves as clients for Ignite. We use `ignite-core` and `ignite-spring` dependencies in these services.

These service starts to produce errors like that after several days of uptime:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -4 out of bounds for length 16
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.getReadHoldCount(StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.topology.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.holdsLock(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheGroupContext.isTopologyLocked(CacheGroupContext.java:678)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.toCacheObject(GridCacheContext.java:1863)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.mapSingleUpdate(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:553)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:458)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.mapOnTopology(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:255)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$26.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1159)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$26.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1157)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.asyncOp(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:782)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1157)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.putAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:661)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:2998)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:2981)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.putAsync0(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1339)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Index -4 out of bounds for length 16
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7628)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl$7.applyx(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1344)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl$7.applyx(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1341)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteClosureX.apply(IgniteClosureX.java:38)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.applyCallback(GridFutureChainListener.java:78)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.apply(GridFutureChainListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.apply(GridFutureChainListener.java:30)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:354)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter$ChainFuture.<init>(GridFutureAdapter.java:588)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.chain(GridFutureAdapter.java:361)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.putAsync0(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1341)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.putAsync(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1326)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.putAsync(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:880)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

The index specified in the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is different for different exception instances but it's always a negative value.

After restarting the services, the error goes and the services work fine next several days. But then the error appears again.

I investigated it a bit and found the error may be causes by overflowing `IDX_GEN` value in [StripedCompositeReadWriteLock](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/util/StripedCompositeReadWriteLock.java#L37) since this value is always increased. If there are a lot of calls to the lock class it maybe overflowed. But it's just my guess and I'm not 100% sure.

Is there other possible causes for the error?
Or maybe some workaround how to avoid this issue. I'd like to avoid periodically restarting a whole service just to reset the `IDX_GEN`

Ignite version and ignite dependencies versions is 2.11.0
Java 18

Comment: Hi, this looks like a bug. Please create a Jira ticket for that and if possible attach full stack trace (with thread name) and actions to reproduce (looks like in your case there were a lot of putAsunc operations)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: @solveMe Thanks for the response. I will create a Jira ticket in this case. And yes, our services do a lot of putAsync calls.